# List files inside ZIP

Tags: windows, zip

I've got ~50 zip files, each containing a similar directory structure but with different files inside.

Is there a way I can easily `dir` the contents of those zips?

I'm interested in creating a list of all the files with their relavite paths, such as `a/b/c/file.txt`

Answer (score 5):

[**Download the command-line version of 7-zip**](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) (7za) and do a `7za -l`.  This will list the contents of the file.  You can then, of course, put this into any kind of batch script.

Comment: The 'l' is a command, not a switch, so the correct invocation is "7za l your_archive.zip"

Answer (score 4):

- Info-Zip's [**UnZip**](http://www.info-zip.org/UnZip.html) (in `zipinfo` mode):

  ```
  unzip -Z1 foo.zip
  zipinfo -1 foo.zip
  ```

  More information:

  ```
  unzip -Z foo.zip
  zipinfo foo.zip
  ```
- **7z**:

  ```
  7za l foo.zip
  ```

Answer (score 4):

If you have jdk you can try jar:

```
$ /cygdrive/c/jdk1.6*/bin/jar -tf tcpmon-1.0-bin.zip
tcpmon-1.0-bin/
tcpmon-1.0-bin/apidocs/
tcpmon-1.0-bin/apidocs/org/
tcpmon-1.0-bin/apidocs/org/apache/
tcpmon-1.0-bin/apidocs/org/apache/ws/
tcpmon-1.0-bin/apidocs/org/apache/ws/commons/
tcpmon-1.0-bin/apidocs/org/apache/ws/commons/tcpmon/
tcpmon-1.0-bin/apidocs/org/apache/ws/commons/tcpmon/class-use/
```

Comment: will this work with wildcards? e.g., *.zip ?

Answer (score 0):

in windows ,install 7zip then open the app path,make "7z.exe" shortcut to the zips folder ,input command to the .bat file:

```
for /f %%i in ('dir /b *.zip') do 7z.lnk l "%cd%\%%i" >>mylist.txt
```

#that is a basic function for current folder path only

#use other extension just change "*.zip" example: "*.7z" .....